# Обработка информационных сообщений в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Загружаю файлы в список в своем приложении для дальнейшей работы с ними, параллельно в другом(не моём) приложении отображается подробная информация по каждому файлу. На некоторых файлах вылетает сообщение во втором приложении: "этот файл может быть открыт только для чтение" и просит нажать "Ок". Мне приходится кликать вручную, это неудобно и нарушает задумку - автоматизацию. Тем более что файлов планируется открывать много. Так же при закрытии своего приложения, закрывается и второе, но оно на каждый файл выкидывает сообщение: "Сохранить изменения?" и соответственно снова ждет моего вмешательства, нажать "Да", "Нет", "Отмена". Как отловить эти сообщения не в моем приложении, зная заголовки, и заставить их нажать кнопки "ок" или "нет" - не сохранять?

Comment: Судя по описанию, вам и там и там надо открывать файлы в режиме "только для чтения"

Comment: Тогда то, второе, не моё приложение будет на каждый файл выдавать "файл только для чтения", а мне вот как раз нужно сделать так, чтобы эти сообщения ловились и автоматически прокликивались, ну и при закрытии файлов тоже

Comment: Не файлы делать "только для чтения", а открывать их в режиме "только чтение"

Comment: @Kromster  мне в любом случае нужно каким-то образом ловить сообщения того приложения. Я лишь используя его API автоматизировал некоторые функции и использую их в своей программе. Так что и при открытии и при закрытии файлов, я получаю какие-либо сообщения к пользователю из той программы, и их нужно закрывать автоматом. Через FindWindow они не ловятся... возможно потому что само сообщение без фокуса?.. всяко попробовал уже

Comment: Какой-нибудь AutoIt примените